# Does clang++ do threadsafe initialisation of local static variables?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

Does clang++ do threadsafe initialisation of local static variables?

GCC does, unless you turn it off with the misleadingly named `-fno-threadsafe-statics`. 
I'm using Apple clang version 2.0 (tags/Apple/clang-139) (based on LLVM 2.9svn).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, same as with GCC (so can also be turned off with `-fno-threadsafe-statics`)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although Apple's libcppabi implements this in a suboptimal way: with a global mutex which harms performance if many threads are using many local statics.

Source code:
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libcppabi/libcppabi-26/src/cxa_guard.cxx

Bug report:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-33967 (which led Qt to implement this differently when libcppabi is used).

I hope making more people aware of this will result in Apple fixing their code one day...